# Conectar una Base de Datos de Access con Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, ms-access

Soy nuevo en StackOverflow y recién iniciado en R y Rstudio. Les agradecería la ayuda con un problema que me surge al conectar una bbdd accdb a Rstudio.

1. Uso los paquetes library(DBI) y library(odbc).
2. No encuentro la información necesaria para poder acceder directamente a las tablas con esas librerías , me aparece sobre todo información acera de MySQL o PostGreSQL

¿Podrían indicarme como han conseguido conectarse a bbdd, y cual es la forma más sencilla para ello?

Muchas gracias.

Un saludo.

Comment: https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/

Comment: https://r-help-es.r-project.narkive.com/AAKfC2tb/r-es-como-conectar-r-con-una-base-de-datos-access-en-windows-64-bit-rodbc-package